# how to convert data type byte[] in c to delphi?

Tags: c, delphi, delphi-7, converters

This is code I need to convert delphi:

```
LPBYTE readCharBuff = NULL;
BYTE readBuffSize;

readCharBuff = new BYTE[200];
readBuffSize    = 200;

readCharBuff[readBuffSize] = '\0';
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where exactly does Delphi come into this?

Comment: I guess the topicstarter needs to convert above code to Delphi7. But so far it is hard to tell what is the goal of it.

Comment: I need convert the code in c to delphi.

Comment: The code is in fact C++ and it has undefined behaviour because you write off the end of the buffer!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a literal translation:

```
var
  readCharBuff: PByte; 
  readBuffSize: Byte;
```

.

```
readCharBuff := nil; 

GetMem(readCharBuff, 200); 
readBuffSize := 200; 

readCharBuff[readBuffSize] := $0;
```

Comment: While this code compiles in XE, in Delphi7 for indexed access I'd rather use readCharBuff: PByteArray

Comment: I like that you faithfully translated the buffer overrun!  ;-)